# Using EntityManager in a Servlet for a Jtable

Tags: spring, servlets, jpa

I'm very confused. This is my problem:

I have a jtable in a jsp file that connects with a Servlet. To this point everything is OK. In my Servlet I need to connect to a DB through EntityManager, but i can't use it because it gives me NullPointerException. I have a HomeController where I manage EntityManager with no problems, but i can't use their functions from my Servlet. This is my sourcecode:

**HomeController.java**:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(HomeController.class);

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

(...)

/**
 * Lists users by points in desc order
 * 
 * @return list with users ordered by points
 */
public List<Usuario> listaUsuarios() {
    return entityManager.createQuery(
            "select u from Usuario u order by puntos desc").getResultList();
}
}
```

**InvasionServlet.java**:

```
@WebServlet("/InvasionServlet")
public class InvasionServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9049034342389418838L;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(InvasionServlet.class);

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

/* Manejo de tablas */
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (action != null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        if (action.equals("list")) {

            logger.info("loading users list");

            List<Usuario> usuariosOrdenados = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "select u from Usuario u order by puntos desc").getResultList();
            JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(usuariosOrdenados,
                    new TypeToken<List<Usuario>>() {
                    }.getType());
            JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
            String listData = jsonArray.toString();
            // Return Json in the format required by jTable plugin
            listData = "{\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":" + listData + "}";
            try {
                response.getWriter().print(listData);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String error = "{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":"
                        + e.getStackTrace() + "}";
                response.getWriter().print(error);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

I Can't load data from anyway, any suggestion? I think its a obvious problem, but I can't figure that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that (unlike HomeContoller) the Servlet is not (and never will be) a Spring Managed Bean and therefore the EntityManager will never be injected.

As you appear to already be using Spring MVC I would suggest replacing the Servlet with a Spring MVC controller which would look something like the below. Otherwise you need to investigate strategies for getting a reference to a Spring Managed Bean (EntityManager) in a Servlet.

```
@Controller
public class MyController(){

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(path="pathToBeCalled")
    public String loadData(@RequestParam("action") String action){

        if (action != null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

            if (action.equals("list")) {

                logger.info("loading users list");

                List<Usuario> usuariosOrdenados = entityManager.createQuery(
                        "select u from Usuario u order by puntos desc").getResultList();

                JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(usuariosOrdenados,
                        new TypeToken<List<Usuario>>() {
                        }.getType());
                JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
                String listData = jsonArray.toString();

                listData = "{\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":" + listData + "}";

                return listData;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Spring service as decorated by `@Service` (or `@Repository`, both from the `org.springframework.stereotype` package) should suffice in this sense. Shouldn't it?